# C++ Operators pre- and post- incrementing

Tags: c++

I am not understanding the pre/post incrementing of this code example:

```
int1 = 14;
int2 = ++int1;
// Assert: int1 == 15 && int2 == 15
```

In this pre-incrementing example why does int1 == 15? Why is int1 incremented and not just int2?

Then we have:

```
int1 = 14;
int2 = int1++;
// Assert: int1 == 15 && int2 == 14
```

In this post-incrementing example why does int2 == 14? Why is int2 not incremented but int1 is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both `++int1` and `int1++` increment `int1` because that's what the increment operators do: they increment their operand.

The reason that `int2` is 15 in the first example and 14 in the second example because the pre-increment and post-increment operators differ in their return value: The post-increment operator increments the operand, but returns the value that the operand had before being incremented. The pre-increment operator returns the new value of the operand.

Answer (score 3):

```
int1 = 14;
int2 = ++int1;
```

is equivalent to

```
int1 = 14;
int1 = int1 + 1;
int2 = int1;
```

and

```
int1 = 14;
int2 = int1++;
```

is equivalent to

```
int1 = 14;
int2 = int1;
int1 = int1 + 1;
```

Comment: Thanks your answer is very well expressed, I understand.

Comment: It is probably worth noting that this is a very loose "equivalence": it explains the numerical result correctly, but it is not equivalent in therms of sequencing. The process of evaluation of `++` contains no sequence points, while these "equivalent" versions introduce a sequence point into the process, thus making additional guarantees that are not really there.

Answer (score 1):

The preincrement operator increments its operand and returns the incremented value:

```
int i = 0;
++i;  // now i is 1, and the returned 1 is discarded
int j = ++i;  // and now i is 2, and the returned 2 is stored in j
```

The postincrement increments its operand and returns the value *before* the increment:

```
int i = 0;
i++;  // now i is 1, and the returned 0 is discarded
int j = i++;  // now i is 2, and the returned 1 is stored in j
```

Answer (score 0):

With the pre-incrementing example, int1 is incremented and then assigned to int2. With the post-incrementing example, int1 is assigned to int2, and THEN int2 is incremented.

Answer (score 0):

By using ++ either before or after a variable you are incrementing that variable regardless.  What changes about putting it before or after is what is returned from the operation.

Value of int1

int1 = 1;
int2 = int++; //returns int1 value [1] and increments int1 by 1 [2]
int3 = ++int; //increments int1 [2] by 1 [3] and then returns int1 [3]

Answer (score 0):

Your questions are difficult to answer, since there's no way to figure out how they could even arise.

In your first question you are asking why `int1` is incremented. The only possible answer is: *because you incremented it*. You applied the increment operator to it. When you apply the increment operator to a variable (doesn't matter, prefix or postfix), the variable gets incremented. Period.

Now, in both of your examples *you* apply increment operator to `int1`. And now *you* are asking why it got incremented? Sorry, a question like that just doesn't make any sense. If you don't know that *increment* operator *increments* variables, you need to read basic some book first before asking questions.

As for `int2`... You never apply increment operator to `int2`, so it will never be *incremented*. Never. There's no place in your example where `int2` is incremented.

In both cases `int2` is simply assigned a value. That value is the result of increment operator applied to `int1`. And all you need to know in this case is that postfix increment returns the *old* value of its operand (so `int1++` evaluates to `14`), while the prefix increment returns the *new* value of its operand (so, `++int1` evaluates to `15`). This is what you get into `int2` in those two cases.